# How to keep UIView on top in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, toast

I'm using a UIView in UIKit to create a Toast-like functionality in Android.

The method I used is 'bringSubviewToFront'. However, this method has a problem of not maintaining the original position when switching the ViewController to tab, push, present.

So I used the method of adding my own UIView to the window.

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last else { return }
window.addSubview(toastView)
```

In this way, the UIView does not disappear and remains displayed even if a push is performed when the tab is switched. However, The problem is that the UIView is hidden when presenting another View Controller still exists.

When I add UIView from the top view controller and dismiss the top view controller, the added UIView behaves like Toast.

It means that there is a problem of hiding only when adding UIView to Window and presenting another View Controller, is there a way to solve this problem?

I want to keep UIView at the top of any situation.

[image]

Comment: You can create your own window and add your view inside that window instead of using main window

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a custom `UIWindow` class that lets you specify a view to keep on top.

Start with:

```
class MyWindow: UIWindow {
    var topView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            if let topView {
                // Make sure the view is actually assigned to this window
                if topView.window === self {
                    bringSubviewToFront(topView)
                } else {
                    self.topView = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        super.addSubview(view)

        if let topView {
            bringSubviewToFront(topView)
        }
    }

    override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        if let topView, subview === topView {
            self.topView = nil
        }

        super.willRemoveSubview(subview)
    }

    override func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: UIView) {
        super.bringSubviewToFront(view)

        if let topView, view !== topView {
            super.bringSubviewToFront(topView)
        }
    }
}
```

Then change any `UIWindow` references in your AppDelegate and/or SceneDelegate to use `MyWindow` instead of `UIWindow`.

Then once you create the view you want to keep on top and add it to the view hierarchy as usual, make one last call to set the window's `topView`.

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last else { return }
window.addSubview(toastView) // Only do this is the view is not part of any other view hierarchy attached to the window
window.topView = toastView
```

Note that this solution doesn't account for any additional windows that may be added to the app at a higher level than the main window.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it might not even be necessary to modify the window. UIWindow is a subclass of UIView, so it can have any number of subviews. It's possible that just adding the "toast" as one of the window's subviews would keep it on screen, and setting its layer's `zPosition` could keep it on top. It's a bit hacky, though.